# R function to switch column names

Tags: r, function

reproducible minimal example dataset

```
pid<-1:30
y1<-rnorm(30,10,10)
y2<-rnorm(30,10,10)
x1<-rnorm(30,5,2)
x2<-rnorm(30,5,2)

data<-data.frame(pid,y1,y2,x1,x2)
```

This is small reproducible example, but I have more variables such as I1, I2, etc...

I am trying to make a function that can switch the function name so that 'y1' become 'y2'
and 'y2'become 'y1'
'x1' become 'x2' and 'x2' become 'x1'

```
rename<-function(data=data,
                 
                 dv=y,
                 IV=x,
                 number_of_IV=1){

   
rename_with(
  data,
  .fn=~gsub(
    pattern='1^',
    replacement='2',
    .x
  ),
  .cols=matches('^y'|'^x')
)
  
rename_with(
  data,
  .fn=~gsub(
    pattern='2^',
    replacement='1',
    .x
  )
  .cols=matches('^y'|'^x')
  )
)
 
}
```

However, it does not work.

```
trouble shooting the fuction that I wrote, so that I can use that function.
```

Comment: and why would you want to do that? What is your main goal?

Comment: Generally, swapping 2 names requires a temporary 3rd name. If you wanted to switch `A` and `B`, you would first switch `A` to `C`, then `B` to `A`, then `C` to `B`. You can take the same approach here - change 1 to 3,  then change 2 to 1, then change 3 to 2. (Or pick something more unique than 3 if needed.)

Comment: Maybe instead of `data<-data.frame(pid,y,x)` `data <- data.frame(pid,y1,y2,x1,x2)` for creating the reproducible minimal example dataset?

Comment: I want this to write my function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want this? Seems like an [`xy problem`](https://xyproblem.info/)

Anyway here is one way to do it

```
head(data)
  pid       x1        y1       x2         y2
1   1 5.087567  4.424669 6.830336 11.6921347
2   2 4.386710 21.870220 1.898388 21.0484717
3   3 5.154918  4.103774 7.926982  4.3101622
4   4 2.528215  3.572182 5.407407  8.3941766
5   5 6.003412 13.877344 6.188354  0.1214239
6   6 8.527333  6.971523 4.559890  7.3657691

head(data) %>%
   rename_with(~str_replace_all(.,"\\d$", ~abs(2-as.numeric(.))+1))

  pid       x2        y2       x1         y1
1   1 5.087567  4.424669 6.830336 11.6921347
2   2 4.386710 21.870220 1.898388 21.0484717
3   3 5.154918  4.103774 7.926982  4.3101622
4   4 2.528215  3.572182 5.407407  8.3941766
5   5 6.003412 13.877344 6.188354  0.1214239
6   6 8.527333  6.971523 4.559890  7.3657691
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chartr` to change `1` to `2` and `2` to `1`.

```
head(data, 2)
#  pid       y1        y2       x1       x2
#1   1 31.54238 -3.972442 5.178496 4.370217
#2   2 22.21881 11.122397 4.384974 4.177646

names(data) <- chartr("12", "21", names(data))

head(data, 2)
#  pid       y2        y1       x2       x1
#1   1 31.54238 -3.972442 5.178496 4.370217
#2   2 22.21881 11.122397 4.384974 4.177646
```